# isIdleTimerDisabled = true works but setting back to false won't dim the screen again

Tags: ios, ios13

This is an iOS 13+ only app.

I want to let the user decide if the main view controller of my app prevents screen dimming or not. That view controller has in viewDidAppear:

```
UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = GlobalSettings.keepScreenOn // my setting variable
```

In viewDidDisappear it has:

```
UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = false
```

The intention is that whenever this VC is not on screen, screen dimming should work normally. While testing the feature, I see that once I turned the setting on, the screen won't dim again whether I let it sit in another VC, and whether I turn the setting off again.

Any ideas??

Comment: Make sure you are not testing while connected to Xcode.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy, please post as an answer and I'll accept it. I find it weird that before trying the setting, it would dim the screen even while connected to Xcode!